# How do I install the latest developer package for wine with homebrew? (wine-3.0-rc2)

Tags: terminal, homebrew, wine

When I type in:

```
 brew install wine
```

That should install Wine 2.0.3, right? (the latest release)

But I want to install a specific version of wine: wine 3.0 rc2

What would the command to do this be if I'm using homebrew? I've tried

```
 brew install wine-devel
```

But it gives me this error:
Error: No available formula with the name "wine-devel"

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Currently `wine-devel` has been moved to `caskroom/versions`. Therefore in order to install `wine-devel` you have to

1. Tap caskroom/versions, by running `brew tap caskroom/versions`
2. Update homebrew (...just to be sure) by running `brew update`
3. Finally install wine-devel by running `brew install caskroom/versions/wine-devel`

Answer (score 5):

`caskroom/versions` was moved to `homebrew/cask-versions`.

The following will work:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install homebrew/cask-versions/wine-devel
```

You will be asked for your password.
Then you should be able to start executables as follows:

```
wine /path/to/app.exe
```

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to install `wine-devel`, but ran into a similar problem. It seems that the answers here may each have been relevant on a different year, as the casks have moved around back and forth. So here's the latest on the situation, and some info on how to handle it in future.

The official instructions (as of 4th April 2020) say to run `brew cask install wine-stable`. However, that leads to an error:

```sh
$ brew cask install wine-stable
Error: Cask wine-staging exists in multiple taps:
  homebrew/cask-versions/wine-staging
  caskroom/versions/wine-staging
```

This means that two potential casks were found, each with the same name, yet each on a different repository, and Homebrew was unsure which one to install.

Running this command gave me a clue about what was going on:

```sh
$ brew tap caskroom/versions
Error: caskroom/versions was moved. Tap homebrew/cask-versions instead.
```

So I learned that you can untap third-party repositories, and untapped the one that the message seemed to advise not to tap WINE casks from.

```sh
$ brew untap caskroom/versions
Untapping caskroom/versions...
Untapped 156 casks (463 files, 56.7MB).
$ brew cask install wine-stable
... Success!
```

Comment: This answer helped me in Sept 2020... Thanks mate :)

Answer (score -1):

To install the development version just pass --devel

```
brew install --devel wine
```

Comment: I got this message when I ran that command. `Error: No devel block is defined for wine`

Comment: Same here, i get "no devel block is defined for wine"